# Shared project in different solutions makes Visual Studio compiler fail (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server, client

I have a server-client application in C#. The client and server are separate solutions and share common code. For development it is crucial, that the shared code is available in each of the solutions (.sln files) as it is constantly changed. Currently, the shared code is added as extra project. However, when I run/debug the server and the client from Visual Studio 2015 the compiler produces (sometimes):

> Error CS2012 "...\obj\Debug\Tools.dll" cannot be opened because it is blocked by another process.

I start two instances of Visual Studio for the two solutions. Presumably the other instance of Visual Studio is blocking the .dll. Restarting/building the client may solve this issue, *but not always which is really annoying*. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Just a thought - remove the common code from BOTH solutions and put it into its own solution. Then maybe publish it as a NuGet package from your build server and consume it in your other solutions via that NuGet package. Doing it your way is horrendous.

Comment: Add Shared folder either in project or in any branch and put all shared dll within it. download it at local machine in the same location at both/all machine.  Add reference of these dll in your project. this will work. let me know if you still facing the issue.

Comment: I'd go the other way and ask why the projects are split into 2 solutions... If they were consolidated into a a single solution, there would be a number of advantages.

Comment: Based on what criteria can I decide what's best for my project? 1. Merge solutions, 2. Make a NuGet package, 3. Add a reference to a shared folder?

Comment: IMO, you'll have the minimum amount of friction while developing by placing all your projects under one roof.

Comment: But then it's not possible to run and debug both application at once via Visual Studio, is it?

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy You can set more than one startup project in VS. Right click the solution node and choose `"Set startup projects"` Then you can debug them concurrently.

Comment: @spender I finally found time to test your approach and I am absolutely flashed by the result. The solution is now organized in folders and everything starts smoothly from one instance of Visual Studio. However, a colleague had an issue debugging the project: He said the debugger could not handle a break point in our Logger (a shared project). He wanted to debug the Logger from Client site, but by chance the Server called the same Logger method at the same time and VS couldn't handle this situation. Any tips for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer proposed by @spender seems to be the ideal solution for this case.
I made a new solution called "Superbuild" organized like this:

```
Superbuild-Project
* Client\
  * Client-project 1
  * Client-project 2
   ...
* Server\
  * Server-project 1
  * Server-project 2
   ...
* SharedProjects\
  * Shared-project 1
  * Shared-project 2
   ...
```

You can easily achieve this by just opening all existing solution files into the new Superbuild solution. Visual Studio 2015 automatically recognized that a couple of projects are imported twice. I moved them to a new folder called "SharedProjects". For starting Client and Server at the same time, you can right click on the Superbuild solution and select `"Set startup projects"` and choose the respective Client and Server project. This way you may run everything with a single instance of VS and debug both applications at the same time. In any case, you can always go back to your old solutions files. Thanks a lot to @spender for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a web server project than a desktop or mobile client app that accesses that.
When I want to work on the client app and need the server to run in the background, I run the client app as "Start without debugging" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) to launch the server, then run the client.